# GeoPandas.explore MultiPolygon not serializable

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have my own dataset containing MultiPolygon definitions, and I want to plot them using GeoPandas `explore` function. I have followed the steps outlined at: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/introduction.html, but at step 10 of their Jupyter notebook, I get an error

```
TypeError: Object of type MultiPolygon is not JSON serializable
```

Here is an example row from my GeoDataFrame:

|  | _id | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 425c... | MULTIPOLYGON (((-13143224.221 4028014.525, -13... |

I have `geopandas` version 0.12.2 and `folium` version 0.14.0 installed.

I have also tried to convert the `geometry` column using `json.dumps` on the output of `shapely.geometry.mapping` before calling `explore`, but then I get this warning:

```
UserWarning: Geometry column does not contain geometry.
```

Trying to plot the mapped values using `explore` gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Input must be valid geometry objects
```

This all seems contradictory, so I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual code you’re running (not just a link) and the full traceback when asking about errors. Thanks!

Comment: hey, just a guess, but I think calling `gdf.explode()` to convert the multi-ploygons into a series of polygons before plotting might be a suitable quick-fix...

Comment: @raphael great suggestion! After exploding the `geometry` column, I was still getting the same error when trying to call `explore`. It turns out, during all my testing, that I must have accidentally duplicated a geometry column. TIL that `explore` takes the remaining row values and adds them to popup messages in the rendered map, hence the serialization error as it was trying to turn another MultiPolygon entry into a string for display as text.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327197/typeerror-input-geometry-column-must-contain-valid-geometry-objects => for the Error issue

Also look at
https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1513 => for the warning issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).